# how to test in bash which of the two symlinks is older (or newer)

Tags: bash, symbolic-link, date-time, ext4, timestamp

Apparently, the bash tests `-nt` and `-ot` dereference links.

Let's consider the following files and links to them:

```
$ ls -lt --full-time f* | cut -d ' ' -f 6-
2023-04-24 02:05:01.083919712 +0200 f1l -> f1
2023-04-24 02:04:56.667857553 +0200 f2l -> f2
2023-04-24 02:04:41.667646860 +0200 f2
2023-04-24 02:04:38.947608730 +0200 f1
```

As you see, f1 is older than f2, which is older than f2l, which is older than f1l.  However, bash doesn't think so, dereferencing the symlinks:

```
$ if [[ f1l -ot f2l ]]; then echo "f1l is older than f2l"; fi
f1l is older than f2l
$ if [[ f2l -nt f1l ]]; then echo "f2l is newer than f1l"; fi
f2l is newer than f1l
```

In bash, how to programmatically test which of two given symlinks is older? We wish to compare the dates&times of the links themselves rather than of the referenced files. (You may assume ext4 file system if that helps.) The test should provide us with a return value, so that we can write stuff as (for a yet-to-be-determined `is_older $1 $2`):

```
if is_older $1 $2 then echo "$1 is older than $2"; fi
```

Comment: `stat` will give the timestamp of the symlink itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` does not dereference links by default and its `-newer` primary tests the mtimes:

```
find f1l -newer f2l       # will "find" f1l
find f2l -newer f1l       # will be silent
```

With your `f1` and `f2` the result will be opposite:

```
find f1 -prune -newer f2  # will be silent
find f2 -prune -newer f1  # will "find" f2
```

(`-prune` in case `f1` or `f2` is a directory).

If each command of the pair is silent then it means the two respective files are equally old (or at least one mtime was unfortunately modified in the meantime).

In each case the exit status will be `0` (unless some critical error happens, e.g. one of the files does not exist). This means you cannot simply use the exit status of `find` like you would use the exit status of `[`  or `[[`.

Remember you can add `-exec` at the end to make `find` do something if the `-newer` test succeeds. Or you can pipe to `grep -q .` to test if the command is not silent and to get the exit status from `grep`.

```
find f1l -newer f2l | grep -q . && echo 'f1l is newer'
find f2l -newer f1l | grep -q . && echo 'f2l is newer'
```

The part before `&&` (i.e. `find … | grep …`) returns success/failure via its exit status, so it can be used where you would otherwise want to use `[` or `[[`. Mind this: [*Has `grep --quiet` a bug with its exit status?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/743260/108618)

Note `grep -q .` would not detect what we want if the tested filename was containing newline character(s) only; but here you know the exact filenames and they are not like this. If they can be like this then you should fix the commands in the following way:

```
find "$file1" -prune -newer "$file2" -exec echo a \; | grep -q a && printf '%s\n' "$file1 is newer"
```

The above command is universal and quite robust (it handles pathnames with newlines, spaces, anything allowed in pathnames). If your `find` supports `-printf` (GNU `find` does) then you probably want `-printf 'a\n'` instead of `-exec echo a \;`, especially if you're going to call `find` many times. `-exec echo` invokes external executable, `-printf` is handled internally by `find` itself.